# How to convert windows 1252 source files to utf-8 easily (in windows)

Tags: encoding, utf-8

I have an Intellij/Maven/Java project I am taking over where the previous developer wrote everything to be encoded in windows-1252 encoding.  Does somebody know of a simple way to convert a set of files (ie all source, properties, xml, text) files from windows-1252 to utf-8?

Comment: Which operating system? On linux, `iconv` does the job.

Answer (score 4):

maybe this is what you are searching for:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cp-converter/